# Cite various python packages in paper

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, citations

We have a working tool built off of various packages in python. I am not sure how to cite these packages for a paper I am working on. How do I properly cite python packages? One of them have a way they ask us to cite them  via a book. Most say nothing on citations that I can find. Is there a standard?

Comment: [How to cite a webpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming but about professional writing.

Answer (score 13):

This link has the preferred citation method for scipy and its related packages. If you aren't using one of these packages you could follow the style they use.

https://scipy.org/citing-scipy/

Comment: The corrected link is: https://scipy.org/citing-scipy/

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as for every software. Search for reference preferred by authors on the Internet. Else try to find a manual. If there is no manual, cite it directly as "software" or cite webpage with documentation.

A lot of preferred citations for Python packages are at the [citebay.com,](http://citebay.com/) for example:

Numpy: http://citebay.com/how-to-cite/numpy/

Pandas: http://citebay.com/how-to-cite/pandas/

Answer (score 0):

For people coming across this in the future, the [citepy](https://pypi.org/project/citepy/) library may solve some problems. It won't pick up the "preferred" citations for the vanishingly small proportion of libraries which have them, but it provides a convenient way of generating CSL-compatible citation metadata for either specific libraries, or everything in your virtual environment.

It dumps out CSL-data JSON, which can then be converted into basically anything by tools like [citation-js](https://citation.js.org/).